# fineuploader iframe functionality (IE7-9)

Tags: fine-uploader

So I've been looking for a solution to implement in my site that allows for multiple files and large files (>2 GBs) to be uploaded, without using any plug-ins, desktop clients, etc. I also have a requirement to support browsers as far back as IE 7. FineUploader seems to fit the bill perfectly, but one aspect I have been trying to figure out is how it uses iframe to support non-HTML5 browsers? Is it basically serving up HTML content, so it still allows users to upload files, but with legacy limitations (one file at a time, not able to read file size prior to upload, etc.)? What functionality of FineUploader do I lose in non-HTML5 browsers?

Thanks,
Stas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the maintainer of Fine Uploader and I will provide an answer to your questions.

For browsers that do not support the File API (IE9 and older, Android 2.3.x) Fine Uploader must rely on a commonly known "trick" to allow for "ajax" uploading.  In these browsers, you must submit a form containing a file input element (one for each file).  Fine Uploader creates a hidden iframe containing a form and a file input for the associated file.  A separate iframe is created for each selected file.  Fine Uploader then submits the form when it comes time to upload the associated file or files.  The response text from the server is loaded into this iframe when the server response is received, and the library parses this response (which must be a valid JSON response, regardless of the browser).

The following limitations are in place on non-File API browsers:

- You can only select one file at a time (one per "choose a file" dialog).  This is due to the fact that none of these browsers do not support the `multiple` attribute on file input elements.
- Dragging and dropping of files is not supported.  This feature depends on File API support.
- Progress bars do not appear, as there is no easy way to determine the upload progress of a file in browsers that do not support the File API.  There may be efforts in the future to allow for progress calculation, such as a documented convention that results in periodic GET requests to check the progress, or support for the UploadProgress module in nginx or apache.
- Client-side file size information is not available.  So, any features related to or dependent on file size are not enabled.  This information is simply not available unless the browser supports the File API.
- Chunking and auto-resume features are not enabled since this explicitly depend on File API support.

Luckily, all "modern" browsers, including IE10, support the File API.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yep, this is exactly the info I was looking for and makes perfect sense. Thank you!